# WSO2 API Manager 2.6: apimcli export-api error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am facing errors while trying to export APIs from my local installation (Windows 64 bit). I have WSO2 API Manager 2.6 installed on my machine with no fixes.

**The error is as shown below:**

```
*c:\apimcli-2.0.3-windows-x64\apimcli>: apimcli export-api -n weatheralerts -v v1.0 -r admin -e APIM-DEV -k
Login to APIM-DEV
Username:admin
Password:apimcli: Error getting credentials Reason: The handle is invalid.
Exit status 1*
```

**I tried to login and notice this error:**

```
> *c:\apimcli-2.0.3-windows-x64\apimcli>apimcli login APIM-DEV -u admin -p admin -k --verbose Executed ImportExportCLI (apimcli) on Wed, 18 Mar 2020 01:50:30 CET [INFO]: Insecure: true Warning: Using --password
> in CLI is not secure. Use --password-stdin Getting ClientID,
> ClientSecret: Status - 403 Forbidden Error: %!s(<nil>) Body: <!--   ~
> Copyright (c) 2016, WSO2 Inc. (http://www.wso2.org) All Rights
> Reserved.   ~   ~ WSO2 Inc. licenses this file to you under the Apache
> License,   ~ Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
> except   ~ in compliance with the License.   ~ You may obtain a copy
> of the License at   ~   ~ http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0  
> ~   ~ Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,   ~
> software distributed under the License is distributed on an   ~ "AS
> IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY   ~ KIND, either
> express or implied.  See the License for the   ~ specific language
> governing permissions and limitations   ~ under the License.   -->
> <html>
>     <head>
>         <title>Error 403</title>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>         <h1>Error 403 - Forbidden</h1>
>     </body> </html> Error occurred while login :  Request didn't respond 200 OK: 403 Forbidden*
```

Please let me know if anyone has any pointers to fix this issue.

**main_config.yml looks as under:**

```
   *config:   
        http_request_timeout: 10000
        export_directory: .wso2apimcli\exported 
    environments:   APIM-DEV:
    api_manager_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443
    api_import_export_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api-import-export-2.5.0-v1
    api_list_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.12/apis
    application_list_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api/am/store/v0.13/applications
    registration_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/client-registration/v0.13/register
    admin_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api/am/admin/v0.13
    token_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:8243/token*
```

Regards,
Buzzman

Answer (score 1):

The API versions in your configuration is wrong. It should be 0.14 for APIM 2.6.0.

```
    api_list_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api/am/publisher/v0.14/apis
    application_list_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api/am/store/v0.14/applications
    registration_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/client-registration/v0.14/register
    admin_endpoint: https://192.168.2.124:9443/api/am/admin/v0.14
```